# Delete a child entity without deleting the parent entity with @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to **delete a child entity from a parent entity**.

I've found that **if I delete the child it will also delete the parent**.

**One To Many**

```
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
             mappedBy = "giftList", 
             fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
             orphanRemoval = true)
   private Collection<Gift> gifts = new HashSet<>();
```

**Many To One**

```
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, 
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private GiftList giftList;
```

**@DeleteMapping**

```
@DeleteMapping("/gifts/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Gift> deleteGiftById(@AuthenticationPrincipal UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, @PathVariable("id") Long giftId) {
    final Optional<Gift> giftListOptional = giftRepository.findById(giftId);

    if(giftListOptional.isPresent()){
        final Gift gift = giftListOptional.get();
        if(gift.getGiftList().getUser().getEmail().equals(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.getName())){
            giftRepository.delete(gift);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

I've tried setting the cascade type for the gift list to `CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH` ,but this stops the gift being deleted as `CascadeType.REMOVE` isn't included.

If I add `CascadeType.REMOVE` then the `gift` and `giftlist` will be removed.

What cascade types should I be using?

Comment: Try to set `orphanRemoval = false`

Comment: Tried that and it still deletes the parent

Comment: Show how you delete the entities.

Comment: I've added the @DeleteMapping

Comment: remove the cascade option from parent

Comment: If I do that then it causes other problems. If I create a new gift list and add a gift and save the gift list, it doesn't save the gift with it. If I have CascadeType.ALL for the @OneToMany then it will save/delete and gifts that I add and remove when I save the gift list.
I want to be able to create a gift list and add/remove gifts etc to it and save it. I also want to be able to remove gifts just by id too and have them remove the link with the gift list without deleting it.

Comment: Until you remove `CascadeType.ALL` (or at least `CascadeType.REMOVE`) from `Gift.giftlist`, it's not going to work, `CascadeType.ALL` **never** makes sense on the 'many' side